# PhpStorm. Auto import namespaces by comma not by "use"

Tags: phpstorm

Can I auto import namespaces in PhpStorm like this way?

```
use Foo/Bar,
    Foo/Bar2,
    Foo2/Bar;
```

Not like this:

```
use Foo/Bar;
use Foo/Bar2;
use Foo2/Bar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible automatically yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15876. You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> though and do that manually (group use statements... PHP intention at File | Settings | Editor | Intentions):

[image: Group use statements by selected prefix]